# Can't get local storage value on initial page load

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

When logging to the console, the following code produces `foo: undefined` on initial page load, but produces `foo: bar` upon subsequents refreshes.

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    let foo = this.storage.get('foo');

    Promise.all([
        foo
    ]).then((result) => {
        this.foo = result[0];
        this.doSomething();
    });
}

doSomething() {
    console.log('foo: ' + this.foo);
}
```

I understand this is asynchronous, but can't figure out how to get the value from storage on initial page load so I can display it in my view. I thought I was doing this correctly?...

Comment: You need to use ngoninit

Comment: You need to use ngoninit. It's a lifecycle hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things: You do not need to wrap this in a `Promise.all` because it is already a promise and further `Promise.all` is for combining multiple promises into one. Also you do not need to wait for `ionViewDidLoad` to fetch something from storage, you can do this right in the constructor. I moved your code into a constructor and added a success and error callback to the promise. I also added another solution using `async/await` syntax:

```
public foo;
constructor(...) {
  this.platform.ready().then(ready => {
    this.storage.get('foo').then(
      result => {
        this.foo = result[0];
        this.doSomething();
      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);
      },
    );

    this.doSomethingElse();
  }
}

doSomething() {
  console.log('foo: ' + this.foo);
}

async doSomethingElse() {
  let bar = await this.storage.get('bar');
  console.log('bar: ' + bar);
}
```

Comment: I did your first example of putting it in the constructor and receive `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null`. I know there's a value in storage bc when I refresh it shows in the log.

Comment: You probably need to wait for the platform-ready event. I'll update my answer.

Comment: It actually turned out to be a race condition, so what I was doing was working anyway - the variable wasn't retrieved from the API until after the page loaded, so I needed to solve that in another way. I'm giving you credit because your answer is the correct answer to my question. Thanks! :)

Comment: Appreciate that! Glad I'm glad you could solve your question!